# I am trying to make a function that takes in a list and gives out an edited list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function, called delta in this case, that will take in an in_list and return and out_list. These are the requirements for the out_list:

1. `len(out_list) == len(in_list)-1`
2. `out_list(i) = in_list(i+1)-in_list(i)`

I wish to use the function on the lists "times" and "positions" in the code below:

```
positionfile = open.("positionmeasurements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
filetext = positionfile.read().splitlines()

times = []
positions = []

for i in filetext:
    time, position = i.split(";")
    times.append(time)
    positions.append(position)
```

This is the code I've got so so far for the function:

```
def delta(in_list):
    for i in in_list:
        out_list = in_list[i+1] - in_list[i]
    return out_list
```

The following numbers are the times (left side of the semicolon) and the positions:

0.05;0.9893835

0.1;0.9921275

0.15;0.989212

0.2;0.98784

0.25;0.9876685

0.3;0.988526

0.35;0.991613

0.4;0.9921275

0.45;0.9921275

0.5;0.9886975

0.55;0.985096

0.6;0.983724

0.65;0.9578275

0.7;0.9163245

0.75;0.8590435

0.8;0.7890715

0.85;0.714812

0.9;0.642096

0.95;0.559776

1;0.4776275

1.05;0.398566

1.1;0.315903

1.15;0.2320395

1.2;0.1799035

1.25;0.181104

Comment: So what problems do you have with this code? Should we guess? I guess `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Unless you have problems parsing that data, you'd better leave that out and provide the input as list of numbers.

Comment: It should be `for i in range(len(in_list))` in the function definition

Comment: The problem is that when I try to use the function on the lists "times" and "positions", I get the error code ` TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Can you show us a piece of your times and positions list and the type of times[1] and positions[1] ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a8f81ca860a51d52454fa4c681097c08 https://gyazo.com/878074d9697ca13d4ecdec8310b9e4ec  https://gyazo.com/ee527e3841a20af15fd4b8ed53c8c71a

Comment: I edited my post, you should convert your list elements into float.

Comment: Thank you, it works now

Comment: Can you accept my answer and vote for please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the list comprehension. As the elements of your list are string, you must convert them into float :

```
def delta(in_list):
    return [float(in_list[i+1]) - float(in_list[i]) for i in range(len(in_list) - 1)]
```

Comment: Same problem here. Your index will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Part of me thinks it'd be more elegant to do this recursively, but the way you've done it is probably better if there's a very long list. Anyway, you're nearly there, you've just mixed up Python's for-loop syntax. `for item in list` gives you the items, `for i in range(len(list))` gives indices to use with the list, which is what you want here.

```
def delta(in_list):
    out_list = []
    for i in range(len(in_list)-1):
        out_list.append(in_list[i+1] - in_list[i])
    return out_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a list comprehension...

```
>>> in_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
>>> [b - a for a, b in zip(in_list, in_list[1:])]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Who neat! Reversing the Fibonacci sequence on top of that.. ! +1